# How can I stack one column on top of other two in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am completely new to Bootstrap(as in just started using it today). I am remaking my website to make it compatible with other screen sizes and devices. I acquainted myself with the grid system today. I basically want 3 columns on my site - one for text, one for images, one for my embedded twitter page. All of them stack at a certain point. When all of them are stacked, I want twitter to disappear. I did it with this jquery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    if(window.innerWidth<992){
        $("#pln").hide();//id for twitter
        $("#label").hide();
    }
    else{
    $("#pln").css("display", "block");
    $("#label").css("display", "initial");
    }

});
```

I minimize my page and realize that there is space for it after the first break point. This is how the page looks after the first breakpoint: [image] On the right, there is enough space for it. I tried changing class col-lg-4 to col-sm-4 for 2 of my columns to have them stack later. This is what I got.[image][image] My images get squashed and twitter does not take up the space it has available. How can I make this look good? [Here](https://output.jsbin.com/cafanacafi) is the jsbin with the whole code there. I am using bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided jsbin, it looks as though the issue is just that your images in the middle row have an explicit `width` property, so they aren't able to fill the full space left over from the Twitter row. Here's the styling that will allow them to stretch, as needed (this should also work on larger screen sizes too):

```
.img-fluid {
  width: 94%; /* play around with this value until you get what you want */
  height: auto; /* maintain image aspect ratio */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As an aside, don't use jQuery for styling (like hiding and showing the Twitter module). Instead, look up and use CSS media queries. CSS is for styling / jQuery is for behavior primarily. Try to keep them separated. You're adding unnecessary load to the browser, when CSS can do it with hardly any. Here's an example query that would accomplish the same thing:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #pln {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

In regards to your question about similarly sized images, here's one solution that I would use. Wrap each image in a common container class:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="someimage.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="someimage.jpg" />
</div>
...
```

And add the following styling:

```
.image-wrapper {
  width: 94%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 62.107142857% /* this is the current aspect ratio of your images */
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

And make sure the static width and border-radius of the images are removed. The wrapper should frame the images, all at the same size.

Comment: I will do that if I can't get twitter to work. In my second image, how can I make twitter take the full width of the space it has?

Comment: Can you tell me what the resolution is you're looking at in the second image? Is the code from that instance reflected in the current jsbin? From a little testing, it looks like the Twitter plugin determines the width when the page is loaded. If you reload the page without resizing, it will look too small / too big for the current dimensions. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: I was using 969x644. That is when I set 2 of the classes to col-sm-4 so that it stacks at different times.

Comment: Ok, got it. So because you want those two columns to take up 50% of the container on small grids, you need to update the class to `col-sm-6`, because that's half of the 12-grid Bootstrap system. `col-sm-4` is only 3/4 of the total container width. Try updating that and it should work (working on jsbin when I tested just now).

Comment: Also for the images, how can I make them all the same width and height? Because they are all slightly different, I used specific width and height to keep them all the same. How can I set my own dimensions, but have the program scale it as I narrow the window?

Comment: So making the images all the same size will be a little more tricky. You can either crop them in the photo editing software of your choice (just make them the same aspect ratio and you should be golden). I'll provide another option with code in my answer above, since it's a little more in-depth.